# The .get() function in Tkinter is returning as None Type

Tags: python, tkinter

When I am trying to collect the data from the input boxes in python with `.get()` it returns as`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'` No matter what I try it doesn't work. Thanks, need all the help I can get.

```
def PETROL():
    Petrol = Tk()
    petrol = Label(Petrol, width=20, text="Petrol", font=30).grid(row=0, column=0)
    PEtrol = Label(Petrol, width=50, text="Enter how much Petrol you have bought in litres.", font=20).grid(row=1, column=0)
    c = Entry(Petrol, width=50, bg="grey", fg="white", borderwidth=4).grid(row=2, column=0)
    Seperator7 = Label(Petrol, text=" ", width=46, height=2).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
    c.get()
    d = c.get()

    Petrol.mainloop()
```

Comment: where's the code ?

Comment: The reason is - your ```c``` is ```None```, so your ```Entry(Petrol(...).grid(...)``` returns ```None```.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you didn't show any code, I'm guessing you did something like this:

```
my_widget = tk.Widget(...).pack()
```

This is a common beginner's mistake. You are creating a widget, but instead of assigning the reference to a variable, you `pack` the anonymous widget in-place and assign the return value of `pack` to `my_widget`, which is always going to be `None`.

You should create the widget and assign the widget reference to a variable, and then let tkinter place it in the layout using `pack` or `grid` in separate steps:

```
my_widget = tk.Widget(...)
my_widget.pack()
```

Answer (score 0):

The widget coded like:

```
a_widget=tk.widget(...)
```

Should be outputted onto the screen with:

```
a_widget.pack()
```

or

```
a_widget.grid(...)
```

and generally not like:

```
a_widget=tk.widget(...).pack()
a_widget=tk.widget(...).grid(...)
```

Your code would be:

```
def PETROL():
 Petrol = Tk()
 petrol = Label(Petrol, width=20, text="Petrol", font=30)
 petrol.grid(row=0, column=0)
 PEtrol = Label(Petrol, width=50, text="Enter how much Petrol you have bought in litres.", font=20)
 PEtrol.grid(row=1, column=0)
 c = Entry(Petrol, width=50, bg="grey", fg="white", borderwidth=4)
 c.grid(row=2, column=0)
 Seperator7 = Label(Petrol, text=" ", width=46, height=2)
 Seperator7.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
 c.get()
 d = c.get()

 Petrol.mainloop()
```